# How to extract values from a dataframe column based on the match of two ID columns of different dataframes?

Tags: r, match, extract

I'm having a little trouble going about this. Basically, I want to extract the values from column MakeText based on the first occurrence of an id match of 2 different dataframes. One dataframe has only unique IDs, whereas the other dataframe has multiple rows of that same ID, hence the clause for the first occurrence. Each unique ID has unique values for MakeText column.

I tried match and merge in r but I have no idea how to extract column values in case of it due to the varying number of rows of the dataframes.

Based on the id of this:

```
 wb <- spread(data = newdata, 
             key = an,
             value = av)

 names(wb)[1] <- "ID"

 wb <- as.data.frame(wb)
 View(wb)

  Id     BodyColorText
  1.0    blue
  100.0  cyan
  1001.0 red
  1003.0 black
```

I want to match it to the ID of this:

```
View(supplierdata)

  Id     MakeText
  1.0    Mercedes
  1.0    Mercedes
  1001.0 Ferrari
  1001.0 Ferrari
  1003.0 Audi
```

and extract the MakeText column values to concatenate it to the wb dataframe with respect to that ID.

As the number of rows are not equal - wb has 1103 while supplierdata has 20957 - I am finding it hard to do this.

The final output that I am looking for is the 'wb' dataframe to look like:

```
  Id     BodyColorText MakeText
  1.0    blue          Mercedes
  100.0  cyan          Porsch
  1001.0 red           Ferrari
  1003.0 black         Audi
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Couple things.  Help us help you by posting your data in a reproducible format (post the output of `dput(head(YOURDATA))`.  Second, what is your final output supposed to look like? Do you want one row per id?

Comment: @BenG Thanks! Thing is I tried posting that earlier, but it was too long to make this question seem reasonable and comprehensible. I have added what my final output is supposed to look like above.

Comment: try `dput(head(YOURDATA, 10))` don't worry if it's long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `left_join`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(wb, suplierdata)
```

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly. I just had to remove the duplicated rows after this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` package :

```
inner_join(wb, distinct(supplierdata), by = 'Id')
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was looking for. I added an edit in my above question to show what the final output is supposed to look like!

Comment: This did however guide me towards the right direction.